# Why (seealldata=true) results into more code coverage?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, bestpractice

I wrote a trigger to prevent more than n incidents for a client(lookup to user) at any point of time.

```
  trigger CountLimit on Incident__c (after insert,after update,after undelete) {
  Set<Id> clientids = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Integer> clientmap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Max_Incidents__c cs = Max_Incidents__c.getInstance('Platinum');
    Integer maxincs = (Integer)cs.MaxIncidentsPerClient__c;

    for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        clientids.add(inc.Client__c);
    }

    Map<Id,User> usermap = new Map<Id,User>([select id,name from user where id in:clientids]);

    for(AggregateResult result:[select count(id) sum, client__c client from Incident__c where client__C in:clientids group by client__C])
    {
        clientmap.put((Id)result.get('client'),(Integer)result.get('sum'));
    }

    for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(clientmap.get(inc.Client__c)>maxincs)
        {
           inc.addError('You can\'t open more than '+maxincs+' incidents for '+ usermap.get(inc.Client__c));
        }
    }
```

And I wrote this test class-

```
@isTest
public class IncidentLimit_Test {
    public static testmethod void testcountincident(){

        User usr = CreateUser('Ben','Bentaleb');
          List<Incident__c> inclist = new List<Incident__c>();  
        try{
        System.runAs(usr){
            Test.startTest();
            for(integer i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
              inclist.add(new Incident__c(client__c=usr.id,Description__c='incident'+i));
            }
           insert inclist;
        Test.stopTest();
        }
       }

    catch(exception e){
      e.getmessage().contains('You can\'t open more than');
      }
        finally{
             System.assertEquals(5, inclist.size());}
               }

public static UserRole CreateUserRole(String name) {
    UserRole ur = new UserRole();
    ur.Name = name;
   insert ur;
    return ur;
}

    public static User CreateUser(String firstname, String lastname) {
    UserRole ur = CreateUserRole('Testing');
         profile pr = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    User usr = new User(FirstName = firstname,
                        LastName = lastname,
                        Username = firstname + '.' + lastname +      '@testing.com',
                        IsActive = true,
                        UserRoleId = ur.Id,
                        Email = 'testuser@testing.com', 
                        Alias = 'tusr', 
                        TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Berlin' , 
                        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
                        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
                        ProfileId = pr.id, 
                        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
                        );
        insert usr;
    return usr;
  }
}
```

The issue I'm here facing is until I add the parameter (seealldata=true) into the annotation the code coverage remains 26% otherwise it's 93%. Please advise.

Comment: I wouldn't of expected your code coverage to vary based on the `seealldata` annotation. Your test is creating a user and setting the `Client__c` to that new user so your trigger should be ignoring all the `Incident__c` records in your org because of this.

Comment: FYI: The reason you are only getting 26% with `seealldata` set to `false` is because your trigger is running on `before insert` which means the `Incident__c` records have not been inserted into the database so your SOQL query returns no results.

Comment: @BarCotter sorry I pasted the wrong code, but the events are (after insert,after update,after undelete) and the result is the same. Can you please think of any other reason?

Comment: Just an FYI. Just like custom objects you have to create data for Custom settings as well. Unless you add `seeAllData=true` you cannot access the custom setting. So try creating the custom setting data in test class, remove the `seeAllData` and check for coverage.

Comment: `Max_Incidents__c.MaxIncidentsPerClient__c` may not be set when using `seeAllData=false`, when it's true you will be using whatever value is set in your org. You test should be creating this custom settting.

Comment: @theGreatDanton Could you please copy your comment as answer? I would like to accept it as the best answer. You spotted it first.

Comment: @BarCotter Thank you that was the issue and it's resolved now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Max_Incidents__c.MaxIncidentsPerClient__c` will not be set when using `seeAllData=false`, when it's `true` you will be using whatever value is set in your org.

Your test should be creating that custom setting as well.

Comment: Another learning I got is custom settings are setup objects. So we have to avoid Mixed DML error.

Comment: Custom Settings are not setup objects. Its the User record that is the setup object in your code. See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm) for a list of setup objects.

Comment: Yes, for few minutes my understanding got broke.

Answer (score 3):

In your trigger not all of the code will execute every time. You have if-statements and for-loops. Which lines of your code are executed depend actually much on the specific data you are processing.

With `seealldata=false` the tests act on a subset of data, usually test-data you create programmatically just for the test.

However if you use `seealldata=true`, the test can operate over the content of you entire database. Because greater variety of records, more lines will be executed in the trigger and your codecoverage is higher. At the same time `seealldata=true` comes with serious tradeoffs, since test-results are depending on variable data, you might loose portability and huge data volume can cause severe performance issues. One example I had a couple of years ago was that code deployment form Sandbox to Production took longer and longer. It started with about 30 seconds and soon reached > 10 minutes. Reason was test-execution with `seealldata=true`. And 10 minutes is just the start: deployments might cost  **hours** after your amount of data has grown big.

To improve the situation without using `seealldata=true`, you need to create better test data so that more lines of your code will be executed. You can use Developer Console to highlight the uncovered lines of code and adjust or extend you test data accordingly.

Unfortunately there is some data you can't create, like the Standard Pricebook. To get related code covered, seealldata might by the only option in some scenarios.

As best practice you should avoid `seealldata=true` when possible and use it only in rare cases where really required. At the same time you should try to generate a wide range of test-data programmatically to ensure good coverage.

See also:

- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm